# Method to force update instead of insert when calling SubmitChanges

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm working with Linq to perform a series of SQL queries on a database. When we call `SubmitChanges()` it automatically determines whether it should update or insert a record. However sometimes this automatic method isn't that helpfull.

For example, I've had issues with composite primary/foreign keys on a table and when Linq should have performed an `Update`, it most exclusively went out performing `Insert` statment, which was of course blocked by the database when a specific key composition already existed causing a headache and waste of time...

Therefore I was wondering if is there a way to force an `Update` over an "*usually Linq self-determined*" `Insert` statement. Kinda like there is `.Attach()` `InsertOnSubmit()` is there a counter part to Update?

*Note:* As anyone noticed Linq to Sql takes Delete requests in last place regardless of you called them before or after another insert or update statement, is there any way within Linq to change this?

Thank you for you time.

Comment: As for your note, I dont think so. I ran into this years ago (search my questions).

Comment: get the item first by its composite pk then perform the update

Comment: @leppie: I'm pretty sure you mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/797232/114298  Using a transaction scope :)

Comment: @YuliamChandra That's what I ended up performing with a few tables, adding an extra primary (and now the only primary key) within the table. Unnecessary if Linq was able to pick up composite keys (least I think it can't), or if I knew of others means to make it aware of it.